# unable to get desired results in Autofilter for array of criteria

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am trying to filter a large data set using variable conditions into 88 different sheets. Among one sheet i need data fiter in place that have FORD, NISSAN and TOYOTA in their field value. Below is the code I am using. I get correct results when i use NISSAN and FORD or any two as a combincation. Upon adding third constraint i get no results on my destination sheets.

```
    Range("A1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter field:=9,_
    Criteria1:=Array("=*FORD*", "=*NISSAN*", "=*TOYOTA*"),_
    Operator:=xlFilterValues_
    Range("A1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter field:=3,_ 
    Criteria1:="Preauthorized Debit / Correction", Operator:=xlFilterValues_

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Leased Payments").Range("A1")
```

However this code works

```
    Range("A1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter field:=9,_
    Criteria1:=Array("=*FORD*", "=*NISSAN*"),_
    Operator:=xlFilterValues_
    Range("A1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter field:=3,_ 
    Criteria1:="Preauthorized Debit / Correction", Operator:=xlFilterValues_

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Leased Payments").Range("A1")
```

Anyone can explain what can I do here to get proper filter. I got desired result by performing filter twice but I also have a subtotal in place that mess up the total if I use two different copy-paste operations. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the cells in column **C** look like?..............would a cell EQUAL *Ford* or CONTAIN *Ford* along with other text??

Comment: Column A : Date
B : Flag
C : Description (Major filter criteria)
D: Customer#
E: Bank ID
F : Credit
G : Debit
H : Balance
I : Details (Contains String that i am filtering)

Comment: They contain FORD or NISSAN or TOYOTA along with other text. Hence using the =*.*